# Installed Percona-Toolkit, but no sign of xtrabackup

Tags: mysql-5.5, backup, debian, xtrabackup

I've installed Percona-Toolkit on my Debian (Wheezy) test Server, using

```
dpkg -i percona-toolkit.deb
apt-get install --fix-missing -f
dpkg -i percona-toolkit.deb
```

However, there is no sign of `Innobackupex` in the `/usr/bin` folder. Trying to run it simply gives me `Command Not Found`

I can see all the `pt-xxx` applications in there suggesting the installation worked ok.

I then tried

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A
```

as per the documentation, but that resulted in:

```
. . .
gpgkeys: key 1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A not found on keyserver    
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Followed by

```
apt-get install xtrabackup
```

But that gave me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package xtrabackup
```

How can I get `xtrabackup` (`Innobackupex`) installed as well?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be an issue with our Proxy Server, blocking downloads from percona.com

Running `sudo apt-get update` revealed that every connection to percona.com 'failed', and so I got that added to the approved list, and after that it installed fine.